# Naming convention for models used to (de)serialize request and responses of a REST API

Tags: rest, kotlin, serialization, naming-conventions

I need to create in a REST API client some classes to handle the (de)serialization of the data and I'm not use how to name the classes in a meaningful way.

For example, with the following API

```
GET  /User
POST /Message
```

I thought of using this structure:

```
package com.example.model

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

object User {
    @Serializable
    data class Response(
        val username: String,
        val fullName: String
    )
}

object Message {
    @Serializable
    data class Request(
        val title: String,
        val message: String
    )
    @Serializable
    data class Response(
        val status: Int
    )
}
```

But than I don't know how to handle something like this (let's assume that all the request and response have a different structure):

```
GET    /User
POST   /Message
DELETE /Message
```

I thought of something like this:

```
object UserGet { ... }
object MessagePost { ... }
object MessageDelete { ... }
```

But then I don't know how to deal with this:

```
GET    /User
GET    /User/{userId}
GET    /User/{userId}/AllMessages
POST   /Message
DELETE /Message
```

Is there a convention for this use case? How is this usually handled on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your class names, just add **methods** to them that correspond to supported request methods.

```kotlin
package com.example.model

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

object User {
    @Serializable
    data class Request( // either you or your routing library should parse incoming urls to deserialize this
        val user_id: String
    )
    @Serializable
    data class Response(
        val username: String,
        val fullName: String
    )
    fun get(req: Request): Response {
    } // GET /User/{user_id}
}

object Message {
    @Serializable
    data class Request(
        val title: String,
        val message: String
    )
    @Serializable
    data class Response(
        val status: Int
    )
    fun create(req: Request): Response {
    } // POST /Message
    fun delete(req: Request): Response {
    } // DELETE /Message
}
```

`GET /user` - you need to define behavior for this. I can't see what this would do in your system at the moment.

`GET /user/{user_id}/AllMessages` - this effectively maps onto a different set of resources. A new class may be in order. I would also recommend a more canonical name like `GET /user/{user_id}/messages`. That way, you could supply parameters for pagination using a querystring `?limit=1000&offset=900`

```kotlin
object UserMessages {
    @Serializable
    data class Request(
        val user_id: String,
        val limit: Int,
        val offset: Int
    )
    @Serializable
    data class Message(
        val message_id: String,
        val text: String
    )
    @Serializable
    data class Response(
        val messages: Array<Message>
    )
    fun get(req: Request): Response {
    } // GET /user/{user_id}/messages
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that I don't have control of the API, I'm just a consumer (I'm a Mobile developer and the back-end is provided by 3rd party), so I can't make any changes to it. And the one in the OP is just an example, not a real one.

My problem is that the Request and Response for the HTTP methods are different even if the PATH is the same (e.g.: `/myendpoint` with `PUT` will have one Response structure, with `POST` will have another response structure.